# Dos span, uno con icono y otro con texto, me hace un salto de linea usando el d-none d-*-block MD Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Pueden ver la [***demostración acá***](https://jsfiddle.net/axb3ync4/show), mi objetivo es que el texto aparezca al lado del icono y no debajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás es esto lo que buscas:

```
<button type="button" (click)="refreshFilter()" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="fa fa-eraser"></span> 
    <span class="d-none d-md-inline-block d-lg-inline-block d-xl-inline-block"> Limpiar</span>
</button>
```

En vez de usar `d-*-block`, utiliza `d-*-inline-block`.

Saludos!